# How to apply another filter, if one filter is already applied in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to write a code. I 've applied a filter and then I need to apply one more filter after few lines. But the second filter is not getting applied. Here is my code-

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function

Sub occ_const_ashish()
  Dim wb As Worksheet
  Dim bldscrng As Range
  Dim wb1 As String
  Dim i As String, j As String
  Dim arr() As Variant
  Dim arrTemp() As Variant
  Set wb = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
  wb1 = ActiveSheet.Name
  wb.Activate
  LC = Sheets(wb1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  ' Sets the search range as A1 to the last column with a header on the Run sheet
  Set sRange = Sheets(wb1).Range("A1", Cells(1, LC))
  ' With the search range
  With sRange
    ' Set Rng as the cell where "Country" is found
    Set cntryrng = .Find(What:="CNTRYCODE", After:=.Cells(1), _
                         LookIn:=xlValues,  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         MatchCase:=False)

    If Not cntryrng Is Nothing Then
      ' Define LastRow as the last row of data under the Due Date header
      LR = Sheets(wb1).Cells(Rows.Count, cntryrng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
      ' Copy from the Due Date header down to the last row of that column and paste to A1 of Paste Report Here sheet
      'Set rngSourceRange1 = Sheets(wb1).Range(cntryrng(2), Cells(LR, cntryrng.Column))
      Set rngSourceRange1 = Sheets(wb1).Range(cntryrng(2), Cells(LR, cntryrng.Column))
      For Each cell In rngSourceRange1
        i = cell.Value
        rw = cell.Row
        'MsgBox i
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Construction")
          arr = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)).Value2)
        End With
        'arr1 = Application.Transpose(Sheets(wb1).Range(Sheets(wb1).Cells(2, 5), Sheets(wb1).Cells(Sheets(wb1).Cells(Sheets(wb1).Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row, 5)).Value2)
        If IsInArray(i, arr) Then
          'arrayTemp = Filter(arr1, i)
          'MsgBox Join(arrayTemp, ",")
          With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Construction")
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            .Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter
            .Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=i
          End With
          With sRange
            ' Set Rng as the cell where "Country" is found
            Set bldscrng = .Find(What:="BLDGSCHEME", After:=.Cells(1), _
                                 LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                 MatchCase:=False)
            col1 = bldscrng.Cells(1, 1).Column
            j = Cells(rw, col1).Value
            If j = "" Then
              Cells(rw, LC + 1).Value = "BLDSCHEME is BLANK"
              'MsgBox "bldscheme is blank"
            Else
              'MsgBox j
              With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Construction")
                arr1 = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row, 3)).Value2)
              End With
              If IsInArray(j, arr1) Then
                'MsgBox "scheme found"
                With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Construction")
                  If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter
                    .Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter
                    .Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=i
                    .Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=j
                End With
              Else
                'MsgBox "scheme not found"
                Cells(rw, LC + 1).Value = "BLDSCHEME is INVALID"
              End If
            End If
          End With
        Else
          MsgBox "Country not found"
        End If
      Next cell
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know it's not getting applied? When you go to the worksheet and click on the filtered column it shows only one criterion?

Comment: @Masoud yes you are right. It shows only first filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then ...
```

Here you check if the `AutoFilterMode` is false while you have applied a filter in the previous lines. So it goes to the `Else` part and shows: `MsgBox "scheme not found"`.

Modify this part of the code as below to comprehend what I mean:

```
      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Construction")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
         Debug.Print .AutoFilterMode 'before applying autofilter
        .Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter
         Debug.Print .AutoFilterMode 'after applying autofilter
        .Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=i
      End With
```

Also, when you want to use this much if-statements try to make the indentation clear and have some comments (maybe numbering) to make your code legible. Moreover, you can consider using `Select Case`.